# How to get a value from a list using ansible

Tags: json, ansible

i'm actually using ansible and i need to parse a result

result {
"stdout_lines":[
      "# Replication",
      "name:ave",
      "host:10.10.10.10",
      "connected_clients:0",
      "repl_backlog_active:1",
      "repl_backlog_size:1048576",
      "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:90804100",
      "repl_backlog_histlen:1048576"
   ]
}

how can i get the "name" value from this list ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
debug: var=result.stdout_lines[1].split(':')[1]
```

Comment: it doesn't work, The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution that i used